# Is it possible to force visual studios to throw an error if an identifiers is used when its library isn't directly included in the source?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include

When compiling the following source:

```
int main()
{
  exp(1.0);

  return 0;
}
```

the copiler gives the following error: `error C3861: 'exp': identifier not found` because I didn't have the line: `#include <iostream>` above `main()`

However, visual studios won't display the error if a library is indirectly included.  For example, the following code compiles without a problem even though the dependency  of `exp` is in `<cmath>`.

```
#include <istream>
int main()
{
  exp(1.0);

  return 0;
}
```

This is because `<iostream>` includes `<istream>` which include `<ostream>` which includes `<ios>` which includes `<xlocnum>` which includes `<cmath>`.

Is there a way to make visual studios throw an error if I don't explicitly include a library yet try to use one of its identifiers?

Comment: There is no `cmath.h`. That aside, it's up to the implementation to decide which other headers to include in some headers. I guess VS needed `<cmath>` for something in `<iostream>`.

Comment: thanks, fixed the cmath.  Yeah I looked at what libraries were included indirectly by including `<iostream>` and it turns out `<cmath>` is one of those libraries

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [include-what-you-use](http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/). It is a [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)-based tool trying to detect missing and superfluous include directives.